# AWS SDK (C#) - how it create describe instances request that filters-out vms with specific tagkey

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

I've seen several solutions for AWS CLI, but I'm not sure how to translate these queries into aws .net sdk.

Given: Aws .net sdk; AWS instances with specific tag key (e.g. EXCLUDE_ME)

Problem: need to create an instance of Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter that will filter-out vms with specific tag key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to filter on value in order to include, but not to exclude instances in the list returned by DescribeInstances. I created a small example that makes two calls to DescribeInstances. The example uses a Paginator to retrieve the results asynchronously:

```
        class DescribeInstances
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            // If the region of the EC2 instances is different from that
            // of the default user, you need to specify the rgion when
            // you create the client object.
            var eC2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            await GetInstanceDescriptions(eC2Client);

            await GetInstanceDescriptionsFiltered(eC2Client, "IncludeInList", "Yes");
        }

        static async Task GetInstanceDescriptions(AmazonEC2Client client)
        {
            var request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();

            Console.WriteLine("Showing all instances:");
            var paginator = client.Paginators.DescribeInstances(request);

            await foreach (var response in paginator.Responses)
            {
                foreach (var reservation in response.Reservations)
                {
                    foreach (var instance in reservation.Instances)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Instance ID: {instance.InstanceId}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\tCurrent State: {instance.State.Name}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task GetInstanceDescriptionsFiltered(AmazonEC2Client client, string tagName, string tagValue)
        {
            // This is the tag we want to use to filter
            // the results of our list of instances.
            var filters = new List<Filter>
            {
                new Filter
                {
                    Name = $"tag:{tagName}",
                    Values = new List<string>
                    {
                        tagValue,
                    },
                },
            };
            var request = new DescribeInstancesRequest
            {
                Filters = filters,
            };

            Console.WriteLine("\nShowing instances with tag: \"IncludeInList\" set to \"Yes\".");
            var paginator = client.Paginators.DescribeInstances(request);

            await foreach (var response in paginator.Responses)
            {
                foreach (var reservation in response.Reservations)
                {
                    foreach (var instance in reservation.Instances)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Instance ID: {instance.InstanceId} ");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\tCurrent State: {instance.State.Name}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to use a tag to exclude, you need to retrieve the entire list and then, as you loop through the results, check the tag value and skip over those that match your criteria.

If you want to see what values can be used with the Filters property, see the API reference here: [DescribeInstancesRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TDescribeInstancesRequest.html) for information about possible values for the filter property.

For more information about using Paginators, see this article: [Introducing Paginators in AWS SDK for .NET v3.5](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-paginators-in-aws-sdk-for-net-v3-5/)